# Equivalent of moment react in java

Tags: java, reactjs, momentjs, epoch, instant

I have to find the difference between the start and the complete load time event. The start load is in java whereas end is in react.

In react I have this

```
completeLoad = moment();
```

I want to record the initial load time in java and then find the difference between the two. I am not sure how to record time in java in similar format as momemt(). Need some help here.

Comment: You could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to insert the timestamp in milliseconds into a variable (if you're generating the HTML with some template engine), and then just create a new `Date` from that over in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you have [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which models a single instantaneous point on the time-line. [`Instant#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--)  gives you the current instant from the system clock.

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now);
        System.out.println(now.toEpochMilli());
        System.out.println(now.getEpochSecond());
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2020-10-07T17:16:10.487996Z
1602090970487
1602090970
```